# Rails: Increase date by one or for tomorrow

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, datetime

I know it is very very simple but am not getting how to do it.

```
end_time = Time.new(Date.today.year, Date.today.month, Date.today.day, 8, 00, 00).strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

But in above code i want tomorrow instead of today i.e. '+1 day'. How can i do it?

I tried:

```
end_time = Time.new(Date.today.year, Date.today.month, Date.today.day, 8, 00, 00).strftime("%H:%M:%S") + 1.day
```

or

```
end_time = Time.new(Date.tomorrow.year, Date.tomorrow.month, Date.tomorrow.day, 8, 00, 00).strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

But no use. Can anybody answer it?

Answer (score 6):

In rails you can use : `end_time + 1.day` or `1.day.from_now`

Added specific case:

```
if @order.delievery_time.between?(start_time, end_time + 1.day)
   @time = @order.delievery_time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
end
```

Comment: i tried to use it in my query: @order.delievery_time.strftime("%H:%M:%S").between? start_time, end_time + 1.days. But it is giving error: can't convert ActiveSupport::Duration into String

Comment: what if you swtich the strftime and the between?

Comment: u mean something like this: @order.delievery_time.between? start_time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"), end_time.strftime("%H:%M:%S") + 1.days.

Comment: i'd try `@order.delivery_time.between?(start_time, end_time + 1.days).strftime("%H:%M:%S")`

Comment: this gives undefined method `delivery_time'

Comment: Well... typo, but its your attribute: delievery_time:  `@order.delievery_time.between?(start_time, end_time + 1.days).strftime("%H:%M:%S")`

Comment: yeah right! its mistake on my side. But still it gives can't convert ActiveSupport::Duration into String

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28363/discussion-between-ferdy-and-user2206724)

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use :-

end_date = Date.tomorrow

= date_field_tag :date_of_journey, end_date